# Java: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I have a project structured as

```
myproject/
         moduleA/
         moduleB/
         moduleC/
```

`myproject` has `pom.xml` as

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Now `moduleC` needs `moduleB` code so it references the dependency as

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.org.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

But when I execute the class in `moduleC`, it complains

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
......
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

This happens when my `moduleC` class executes `moduleB` code.

What is that I am doing wrong? how can  I fix this?

Comment: How are you packaging the binaries and how are you executing them? The given `pom.xml` only describes the compile-time dependencies - not how the binaries are packaged. The error message is typically to classpath problems. So the JVM can't find the logback implementation of the `LoggerFactory` class on the classpath.

Answer (score 7):

You are setting your dependencies to 'provided' which means that they won't be included in your runtime classpath.  You are basically telling Maven that you will provide these files at runtime, so they are there for compilation, but unless you put them in your classpath manually they won't be there when you run.

Have a look here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope  for more information on each of the scope levels.

If you specify nothing then the scope will be compile:

> Compile is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

So you can omit your scope tag or explicitly add it as compile and when you run your app the dependencies will be included on the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 1):

as per comment by @Dave, I did added the following to my `pom.xml` and things started to work as usual

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
```