# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory using logback-classic

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

when running my program after building it like this `mvn clean install` then running it with `java -jar target/Sorting-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at xyz.skwar.sorting.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 1 more
```

I researched it myself by reading this [articel](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/02/fix-exception-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory-java.html), it is not related since it has to do with a dependency. I read the following stack overflow posts:

- [1. how to fix "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory" error when run java jar application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650638/how-to-fix-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory-error-when)
- [2. "How to fix: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027860/how-to-fix-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory)
- [3. "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926899/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-loggerfactory)
- [4. Maven with dependency on "logback-classic" still gives "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348764/maven-with-dependency-on-logback-classic-still-gives-java-lang-noclassdeffoun)
- [5. Java: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468448/java-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-logge)

Those all did not fix the problem since I am including the logging libary not just the api, I tried the solution from the 4th one but also did not work. The 5th one also is not relevant since I am not setting a scope.
When I remove the `slf4j-api` it fails with, even though acording to the [slf4j docs](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#projectDep) logback-classic provides slf4j-api:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

And I also made I minimal code sample which still has the problem:

```java
package xyz.skwar.sorting;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Main {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("test");
  }
}
```

And here is also the entire pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>xyz.skwar.sorting</groupId>
  <artifactId>Sorting</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.slf4j.version>2.0.9</org.slf4j.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.30</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>xyz.skwar.sorting.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps to create a fat jar using manual maven configuration.

1. Copy dependencies under `libs` directory (**Missing in your pom**)
2. Create executable jar and specify classpath as `libs` directory. (**You are already doing this.**)

So use `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy the dependencies under `libs` directory and then it should work fine.